# Android Speech To Text Query

Tags: android, speech-to-text

In the background how voice input works is, the speech input will be streamed to a server, on the server voice will be converted to text and finally text will be sent back to our app.

**But My question is**

is it possible that we can get text in real time like if user say hello then app will immediately get hello. I have checked we can get text in onActivityResult.

But currently i am getting text when the user stops speaking.
Can you please tell me is it possible that we can get text in real time, not after stop speaking.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. You can't get text in real time as it's a google algorithm. You can only get text after user stop speaking.